# Check box uncheck Remove <li> item from list

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, checkbox

I want to manipulate the array by checking and un-checking of the check box. I have a array list and I want to remove the item from the array on un-checking check-box. By default list must be shown and checkbox must be checked.

```
<div id="x">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="Home"> Home
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="Mayor Conner"> Mayor Conner
</div>
</br></br></br>

<div class="mainPanel">
  <div id="cssmenu">

  </div>
</div>

var mainPanel = [{
  title: "Home",
  id: "lnk_home"
}, {
  title: "Mayor's Conner",
  id: ""
}];

$(document).ready(function createlist() {
  console.log('createlist called');
  var items = '';
  var ulStr = "<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < mainPanel.length; i++) {
    items += '<li><a href="" id="' + mainPanel[i].id + '">' + mainPanel[i].title + '</a></li>';
  }
  ulStr += items;
  ulStr += '</ul>';
  $("#cssmenu").append(ulStr);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $mlist = $("#menuPanel");

  $(".chkbox").onchange(function() {
    var list = this.value;
    if (this.checked) {
      $list.append('<li>' + mlist + '</li>');
    } else {
      $("#menuPanel li:contains('" + mlist + "')").slideUp(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
    }

  })
});
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mugamboo/hhqh5/5/)

Comment: So you want to remove the Home link when a user checks the Home checkbox. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the Home link when its uncheck, also how would I by default show checkbox checked when all <li> items are showing.

Comment: Please check errors in browser dev tools console! First will see `$().onchange` is not a function... when you fix that will see `$list` is undefined. Your console should be first line of troubleshooting

Comment: 1) Why do you have two `$(document).ready()` handlers?  2) `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onchange is not a function` (did you mean `$(...).change()`?) 3) `$list is not defined` (did you mean `list`?) 4) `mlist is not defined` (did you mean `$mlist`?) 5) `list.append is not a function`...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="x">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="Home" checked=""> Home
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" value="Mayor_Conner" checked=""> Mayor Conner
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="mainPanel">
    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>  </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var arrMainPanel =
                [
                    {
                        title: "Home",
                        id: "lnk_home",
                        class: "Home"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Mayor's Conner",
                        id: "",
                        class: "Mayor_Conner"
                    }
                ];
        arrMainPanel.forEach(function (objSinglePanel) {
            $("<li>", {
                class: objSinglePanel.class,
                html:'<a href="" id="' + objSinglePanel.id + '">' + objSinglePanel.title + '</a>'
            }).appendTo("div#cssmenu ul");
        });

        $(".chkbox").change(function () {
            $("li." + $(this).val()).show();
            if (!$(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $("li." + $(this).val()).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I have a little issue, When I go to some other page, it doesn't save the setting. List shows up even the check boxes are unchecked. Any thoughts.

Comment: I think we should give an if condition before creating a list. If array flag is true create an array element, else go to next. And in the check box flag is true on check and false on unchecked. Can you can me with syntax code for this logic

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few things that were happening here. First the code, then an explanation below:

Try this:

```
var mainPanel = [{
  title: "Home",
  id: "lnk_home"
}, {
  title: "Mayor's Conner",
  id: ""
}];

function createlist() {
  //alert('createlist called');
  var items = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < mainPanel.length; i++) {
    items += '<li><a href="" id="' + mainPanel[i].id + '">' + mainPanel[i].title + '</a></li>';
  }
  $("#cssmenu ul").append(items);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  createlist();

  $(".chkbox").on("change", function() {
    var list = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#cssmenu ul").append('<li>' + list + '</li>');
    } else {
      $("#cssmenu ul li:contains('" + list + "')").slideUp(function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
    }

  })
});
```

What I did:

- Put the `<ul>` as part of the structure of the html (No need to put it in the jquery)
- Fixed the selectors to access the list property
- Corrected the way to check that a `checkbox` has been checked
- Moved the `createlist()` function outside of the `$(document).ready()`
- Got the value of the checkbox using the `val()` function
- Changed the incorrect `onchange()` method to `on("change", ...`
- Moved the variables around. `$mlist` is not valid. Looks like you're mixing up the syntax a bit

Comment: Ok. Try it again now